# Init a function into a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
var wrapper = {
          init: function (elemClass) {
            this.className = elemClass || '.full-description';
            this.wrapElems();
          },
          wrapElems: function () {
            var $lines = $(this.className),
                holder = [];

            $lines.each(function (i, item) {
              holder.push(item);

              if (holder.length === 2) {
                $(holder).wrapAll('<div class="w-row" />');
                holder.length  = 0;
              }
            });

            $(holder).wrapAll('<div class="w-row" />');
          }
        };

    wrapper.init();
```

I want to init the wrapper into a specific div, I try this

```
var init = wrapper.init();
$("#div-content").append(init);
```

It does not work.
Thanks for the help

Comment: `wrapper.init` doesn't return anything. What's the code supposed to do?

Comment: It return <div class="w-row"><div class="full-description">.....</div><div class="full-description">.....</div></div>

Answer (score 1):

you can append like this

```
$("#div-content").append("<script>wrapper.init();</script>");
```

Comment: I just write it like this and it works `$(".div-content").append('<script>wrapper.init();</' + 'script>');` Thanks for your answer ;)